# c# array have a element with condition

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a Class MyClass that have a method MyFunction which return a Boolean. then I have a array MyArray of MyClass and I need to return true if this array have a object where MyFunction returns true, i actually use this:

```
 bool MyOtherFunction () {
     foreach (MyClass x in MyArray.Where(y => y.MyFunction))
        {
            return true;
        }
     return false;
 }
```

But Visual Studio keeps warning me because "Local variable 'x' is never used", So, how can I check this without declaring a new variable?

Comment: Did you want to use an `if` rather than a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the entire body of your function with

```
return MyArray.Any(x => x.MyFunction());
```

Your current function is essentially filtering out any results that do not return true from the call to MyFunction. If there are results, you'll begin enumerating the result of your `Where` filter, and at the first item return true. If there are no results, there will be nothing to enumerate, and you will return false. By using LINQ's `Any` method, you will instead enumerate until one of the item's in the array's `MyFunction` call returns true, at which point you will have met your condition and can return true. If `MyFunction` is a potentially expensive call this will be much quicker than executing the function for every possible element in your array when all you really want is to return if any one happens to be true. Of course, if it is expensive, you're going to be stuck executing it for every element if they all return false.

Comment: The answer is correct, the explanation (how `Where` works) isn't. `Where` (like most of LINQ) is just as lazy as `Any`. So `MyFunction` will not be called more than absolutely necessary either way. In other words, both method bodies work the way you explained `Any`.

Comment: You're right, it would exit out because the return ends execution, thanks for pointing that out.